# One ASP.NET MVC route not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with routing, `RouteConfig.cs` contains these routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "TermsOfService",
    "termsofservice",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "TermsOfService" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "PrivacyPolicy",
    "privacypolicy",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "PrivacyPolicy" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Contact",
    "contact",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Support",
    "support",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Support" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ReadOurStory",
    "readourstory",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "ReadOurStory" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlogItem",
    url: "blog/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "BlogItem" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetail",
    url: "products/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Products",
    url: "products",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Products" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Tutorials",
    url: "tutorials",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Tutorials" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Blog",
    url: "blog",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TutorialDetail",
    url: "tutorials/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Tutorial" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and these two actions in `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult Products()
{
    var model = LoadItemsModel(ItemType.Product);
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Tutorials()
{
    var model = LoadItemsModel(ItemType.Tutorial);
    return View(model);
}
```

Now the link for products is working:

http://localhost:61296/products/

but the link for tutorials:

http://localhost:61296/tutorials/

returns error

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**

**The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory**

I tried to change the route just for a test to `tutorials2` and the action to `Tutorials2` and then this modified link is working. I do not know why the route `tutorials` does not work.

Comment: You're really going against the conventions of ASP.NET MVC by doing it this way.  Each controller is already set up to route to the `Index` action of each controller, based on the controller name.  Create a controller called `TutorialsController` and the existing route (the last route) will route automatically to the `Index` action of this controller.  You don't need to set up a separate route for each one with hard coded values like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error, my guess would be that you have a physical directory in your project folder called "tutorials". Any physical files/directories will always overrule any routes. Then, since directory listing is disabled by default, you get that 403 error. Remove or rename the physical directory and you should be fine.